# Howto convert datetime to date with an ODBC function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, datetime, odbc

Question:

I need to get the DATE ONLY (= date WITHOUT time) **with an ODBC escape sequence**.

However

```
SELECT 
     {fn CONVERT(SomeTable.Col_With_DateTime_Value, SQL_DATE)}
FROM SomeTable
```

does return the column as datetime value (date WITH time).

Is there any **ODBC function** I can use to get the **date** value **only** ?

Note:
This is not a duplicate question. 
I know one can use the **non**-ODBC convert function, like

```
CONVERT(char(8),  getdate(), 112) AS v112_ISO  
CONVERT(char(10), getdate(), 104) AS v104_XML
```

but I really need an **ODBC** function for compatibility reasons.

Comment: sql server 2005 or 2008?

Comment: ... or postgres, its vendor+driver specific

Comment: @Alex: ODBC: OpenDataBaseConnectivity. It defines escape functions that are the same everywhere. But ONLY the escape functions.

Comment: @Diego: Doesn't matter for ODBC. In other words: both! For SQL server 2005 it must return a datetime value with the time component set to 00:00:00, while in 2008, it could return a date value, but would have to return a datetime value to retain backwards compatibility.

Comment: What data type do you expect to have at the end? You can certainly get a string by nesting enough functions: YEAR, MONTH and DAYOFMONTH to extract the date parts first, then CONVERT them to SQL_VARCHAR and finally CONCAT them together into YYYYMMDD or whatever string format you want. You would also need an extra CONCAT and RIGHT to handle months 1-9 because presumably you would want a leading zero. It would be unreadable, but if you can encapsulate it in a function in your application then it might be OK. Have you looked into an ORM or DAL that would handle this for you?

Comment: @Pondlife: Yes, but that's somewhat complex. Simple answer to second question: ORM's don't support that, it's a view, not a query coming from code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this:

```
select {fn convert({fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, 0, DatetimeCol)}, SQL_DATE)}
from SomeTable
```

Works in the environments I have available to test on (SQL Server 2000-2012).

**Update:**

Here is another way that I believe could be faster than using convert.

```
select {fn timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_DAY, 0, DatetimeCol)}, 0)} 
from SomeTable
```

Comment: Great, was thinking about timestampdiff as well, but between date and datetime value. Somehow this variant eluded me. Brilliant in simplicity.

Answer (score -3):

```
select cast(day(getdate()) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(month(getdate()) as varchar(2))+'/'+cast(year(getdate()) as varchar(4))
```

or

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

Comment: Didn't I say 3 (or is it 4) times ODBC - with ODBC in bold ? And one time i added "not  convert" just to be sure ? Somehow the message still didn't arrive... So if you could please explain me where you see an ODBC escape sequence in your answer ? You know, those things starting with {fn(... )} ? You know, everything within fn gets replaced with database-specific functions, yours doesn't get replaced because it isn't an ODBC function, and thus won't work on anything that isn't called Microsoft SQL Server, like PostGreSQL server for example, as you could see from the tags.

Comment: And by the way, variant 1 works only on an SQL server with English localization, variant 2 is just as bad. You're not handling dates correctly. The SQL server specific way would be CONVERT(datetime, {fn CURDATE()}, 120), OR CAST(FLOOR(CAST(DATETIME_COLUMN as float)) as datetime) respectively. BTW, how do you want to compare varchars with <= and => ? (OK this is my fault, the date computed is actually used in the where clause, I wrote it in a select for demonstrative purposes).